# find string in first 10 characters

Tags: mysql, select

I have a table with fields containing html code. I would like to select only those rows where htmlfield contain string "`<p>[[{"fid":`" but only in first 10 characters of the html field (this field contains more of such strings and I want to find only fields that contain the string in the beginning).
Is it possible to do such select?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `SUBSTRING()` to grab the fields with that string in them.

```
SELECT field1
FROM TableName
WHERE SUBSTRING(field1, 1, 12) = '<p>[[{"fid":'
```

[Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d268cd/6)

You can also try using the `LIKE` function. Where you can use the `%` wildcard at the end of your string to get fields that start with that string.

```
SELECT field1
FROM TableName
WHERE field1 LIKE '<p>[[{"fid":%'
```

[Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d268cd/10)

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

```
   select SUBSTRING(field_name,1, 10) from table_name;
```

It will display 10 characters only for that specific field.
Hope it helps

Comment: Hi,I would like to search in first 10 characters for "<p>[[{"fid":" string. How to do that?

Comment: Did you try that query above?What you are going to do exactly? you want to fetch a data from <p> this tag?

Comment: Hi,I can see that the query is not going to find the string. I have updated the question co it is more clear.

Comment: I dont understand what you mean, Do you want to do it in your database?